# How to validate and sanitize array of data in php?

Tags: php, arrays, validation, sanitization

I want to validate and sanitize data which comes from `POST` array.

My `POST` data is something like this:

```
Array
(
    [category_name] => fsdfsfwereq34
    [subCategory] => Array
        (
            [0] => sdfadsffasfasdf
            [1] => sdfasfdsafadsf
            [2] => safdfdasfas
        )

    [category-submitted] => TRUE
)
1
```

I can validate and sanitize `category_name` and this is how I do it in PHP.

```
if (!empty( $_POST['category_name'])) { 
    $category = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'category_name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);  
} else {
    $category = NULL;
}
```

But I do not know how to do it for values of the `subCategory` array. 
Can anybody tell me how can I do this?

Hope somebody may help me out. Thank you.

Comment: Loop through $_POST['SubCategory']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.foreach.php) to loop through all values of an array. In the loop you can push your filtered values to a new array $subCategory (e.g.).

E.g.:

```
$subCategory = $_POST['subCategory'];
$subcategories = array();
if (!empty( $subCategory ) && is_array( $subCategory ) ) {
  foreach( $subCategory as $key => $value ) {
    $subCategories[] = filter_var( $value, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through or for array you use this:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php the same way.

Answer (score 0):

After 7 years I propose an answer that complements Siim Kallari's answer and that evaluates POST variables passed by fetch() from javascript in case it can be useful for someone.

You can also use [filter_var_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var-array.php).

```
$parameters = filter_var_array(json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true), FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is 8 years old now (my god), but you can use

```
$array= map_deep( $array, 'sanitize_text_field' );
```

to recursively sanitize an entire object/ multi-array and set the original array to it's new value.

See [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/map_deep/) and [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/) for more information on the two